# mysql allow invalid dates on select

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason, I can't even select invalid dates in my table. How do I force select? I just receive:

```
select * from table
>> Mysql2::Error: Invalid date: 1900-00-00
```

I'm not trying to insert, just select. Can I set allow invalid dates in select query?

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.61, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.1

mysql> select @@global.sql_mode;
+-------------------+
| @@global.sql_mode |
+-------------------+
|                   |
```

Comment: Can you add your sample query?

Comment: What library are you using? Strict mode turned on?

Comment: I don't know. How do I find out or disable strict mode? I'm using ruby mysql2 library.

Comment: I don't think I have strict mode enabled.

Comment: see related question on how to convert invalid dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933042/mysql-fix-invalid-dates

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is what I do to ignore invalid dates:

```
SET SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

Comment: where do you set this?

Comment: @njoshsn in /etc/my.cnf you can configure mysql, comment by [Martin Eisenführer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7308580/martin-eisenf%c3%bchrer) posted incorrectly in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41192800/5292302)

Answer (score 11):

- Log into mysql in the command line `mysql -u root -p`
- Enter your password
- View the current `sql-modes` using `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;`
- Copy the current modes (add or delete modes as needed) and paste in next step.
- Set the `sql-modes` using `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';`
- This adds `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` and removes both `NO_ZERO_DATE, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`
- Restart the MySQL server `/etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: If you have a default configuration for the MySQL server, it will reset when the computer reboots.

Comment: all good but the sql-modes went back to the default when i restarted the mysql service. It worked for me without restarting the service.

Comment: still the issue persist ! my innodb_version is 5.5.53 on  alter table statements !

Answer (score 5):

### SQL Server Modes [Reset configuration file]

[Solution Link](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-how-to-permanently-change-sql-mode-in-mysql/)
- From the command line `which mysqld`
- Should get something like `/usr/sbin/mysqld` which is the location of the binary file
- Sort out the path for the configuration files `/usr/sbin/mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"`
- Your bash response should look like this: `Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf`
- Look at the files in successive order to see where to make changes (if a file does not exist it is not being referenced).
- Look up your current mode. Open a terminal and log into the mysql database `mysql -u database_user -p -e "select @@sql_mode"`
- Modify the SQL modes you want to change by adding the following code to the configuration file.

`[mysqld]

sql-mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES"`

- Save the configuration file and restart the mysql service

Comment: still the issue persist ! my innodb_version is 5.5.53

Comment: Walk me through the problem?  
Can you login to your mysql database?  
Can you ```use myDataBaseName;``` the correct database?  
Can you ```show tables;``` and see the table you want to reference?  
Can you ```describe myTableName``` of the table you want to utilize?  
What is the data type of the column that contains the zero date?  
What is your current SQL-mode?

Answer (score 1):

This one solve my problem. I tested in local MySQL 5.7 ubuntu 18.04.

```
set global sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

Before running this query globally I added a cnf file in  ***/etc/mysql/conf.d*** directory. The cnf file name is ***mysql.cnf*** and codes

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Then I restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Hope this can help someone.