# MySQL allowing invalid dates to be saved

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, date

i am writing a rails app into which i'll save dates. right now i am trying to replicate a bug where false dates are being saved. but whenever i tried saving then i'd get the following error,

```
Incorrect date value: '10256-05-05' for column 'transaction_date' at row 1
```

so i figured that my MySQL has something different to it. i am running `Server version: 5.6.11` and then came across this [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates) and it mentioned about the MySQL setting  `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`. and then i found this question with some similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932760/mysql-allow-invalid-dates-on-select). so i opened MySQL and ran

```
SET SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

to which i get this

```
mysql> SET SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

but when i exit i and open sequel pro and try saving an incorrect date it gives me the middle finger again. i have created a my.cnf file in `/etc/`

but i have no idea what goes in there. i think thats where i should stick something like `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES` so that it perpetuates. but i am scared of messing with these files. ?? help please :)

Comment: Try running that SET from the application (when you open a connection)

Comment: that worked but it will last for that session. is there a way to set this in the MySQL config

Comment: It will help you reproduce the bug, is this not your goal?

Comment: i can reproduce it but since our systems are all accepting it in any case having to set the `sql_mode` could get annoying

Comment: You can set it in the config. Check [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-sql-mode.html) for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried a few things i eventually reinstalled the `mysql2` gem and then reinstalled the latest mySQL via home brew so that it was a clean install. i then opened sql and

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

Set it as this ^

Then re-opened it and changed the mode to this.

```
set global sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

I can now save invalid dates. These will appear as `0000-00-00` within the db, with no exceptions being raised.

Comment: Nice and simple. Worked. Only using on my local testing MySQL 5.7, which is set up differently to the version in our deployed app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on OS X and using brew's plist for launchctl (basically, if you have done ln -sf /usr/local/opt/mysql/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents) to start the mysql server, I had to edit the plist file like the below to make it start the mysql server process with sql_mode set to a blank.  I tried to change various my.cnf files to take the sql_mode variable setting, but it never worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.mysql</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--bind-address=127.0.0.1</string>
    <string>--sql-mode= </string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```